# change Watir::Browser.new to IE by default

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

**Can I change the default browser  Firefox to  IE in watir**

```
Watir::Browser.new
```

Actually this code open Firefox browser.I want to open IE by default instead of Firefox with this line of code.

**It is possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do so. For that You have to change **browser.rb** file,

```
def initialize(browser = :firefox, *args) 
to
def initialize(browser = :IE, *args)
```

and add IE extension on system path.

Comment: yes it is good idea , if you need to do some thing like that.It is open source any one can change it for own requirement

Comment: I know that,once some long time you spend,you will realize if is this really good or bad.. You don't need to rely on me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use IE with `watir-classic` instead of `watir-webdriver` then you can do that by using `watir` gem on a Windows machine:

```
require "watir"

b = Watir::Browser.new # opens IE with watir-classic
```

The same code will open Firefox on a non-Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you create `Watir::Browser` object,using `Watir::Browser.new` only,then default browser will be always **Firefox**. Because that is how the code has been written in the [**`browser.rb`**](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb#L43):

```
# File 'lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb', line 43

def initialize(browser = :firefox, *args)
  case browser
  when Symbol, String
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for browser.to_sym, *args
  when Selenium::WebDriver::Driver
    @driver = browser
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "expected Symbol or Selenium::WebDriver::Driver, got #{browser.class}"
  end

  @error_checkers = []
  @current_frame  = nil
  @closed         = false
end
```

> I want to open IE by default instead of Firefox with this line of code.

Yes possible as below :

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
```

Or,otherwise you need to replace `:firefox` with `:ie`,in the `#initialize` method. But I would recommend you not to change the source code.

Comment: Yes,I know that but can I open IE by doing Watir::Browser.new?

Comment: @prashantsharma look at the source code. If you don't pass any argument when you are calling `#new`,then always `firefox` will be pened.

Comment: why firefox do not need to include in path,like IE and chrome has too

Comment: @prashantsharma See the method definition `def initialize(browser = :firefox, *args)` written by author.

Comment: In this I want to replace Firefox with IE. But how?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gotva/cucumber-watir/blob/master/features/support/env.rb
There is settings for environment. IE is presented there. You can use smth like this (pass a env variable) or setup it directly in place you setup watir

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
Browser = Watir::Browser
browser = Browser.new :ie
```

Comment: that was not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it is done this way:

b=Watir::Browser.start('www.google.com',browser=:ie)

you use Watir::Browser object
start method and augments(url in quotes, type of browser)

Comment: start method is new and goto together